# "preferred respectively" or "respectively preferred"

Tags: sentence-construction, grammaticality-in-context

I want to write a sentence and say something like this:

> After these, X, Y and Z are respectively preferred.

The main purpose is to say that these are the things which are preferred :
1. A
2. B
3. C
4. X
5. Y
6. Z

Which  is correct?  "preferred respectively" or "respectively preferred" ?

---

**More Context:**

For A, B and C I used this sentence: The research showed that most coaches prefer A, B and C.

Comment: In the list, do you mean from _most_ preferred to _least_ preferred, or something like that?

Comment: @Max Yes :) that's exactly what i meant

Comment: Would you tell us how did you describe the priorities of A, B, and C ? I am not sure that using "respectively" is a good idea here. but I am a learner.

Comment: @Cardinal i'm not sure of that either ! for A, B and C i used this sentence :  The research showed that most coaches prefer A, B and C.

Comment: You are welcome to wait much longer for other responses. Don't feel like you need to accept an answer right away. It is normal to wait a few hours, or even a day before you accept an answers. This gives others a chance to respond, especially on a smaller SE like ELL. Have a look at [Not so fast! (When should I accept my answer?)](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/1307/not-so-fast-when-should-i-accept-my-answer)

Comment: @Max I asked another question which 4 person thought it was useful and they voted for it.  I think that question was a good one. But i saw that they put it on hold ! I wanted to wait a bit longer but that reaction made me accept the answer ... i just wanted to say that sometimes others make me do something that i don't want :)

Comment: My "very" general rule is to put the adverb (when modifying a verb) after the verb. So I would go with "After these, X, Y and Z are *preferred respectively*." Though I agree this statement is not the best way to say what you want, since it doesn't say what they are preferred over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think respectively works here.

> [respectively](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/respectively)
>   adv
>   (in listing a number of items or attributes that refer to another list) separately in the order given:
>   *he gave Janet and John a cake and a chocolate respectively.*

This means that Janet got a cake and John got a chocolate.

There is also this definition

> in precisely the order given; sequentially.

But I don't think it would not imply **which** order you intend, high to low or low to high. So, I would not use *respectively* in this case. I would instead consider

> 1. After these, X, Y and Z followed, from most to least preferred.
> 2. After these, X,Y, and Z were preferred, in decreasing order.
> 3. After these, X,Y, and Z were preferred, where X was most preferred, and Z was least preferred.

This is assuming that X was most preferred, and Z was least preferred.