# How to use respectively in my sentence which have or in sentence for two entities

Tags: grammar, word-choice, american-english

currently I am writing one document in which I need to write sentence like below

> The food will be served by X or Y person of W or Z catering service
> respectively.

Now here X is belongs from W catering service and Y from Z catering service. So above sentence is correct? If not then can you please suggest correct one?

Comment: If X and Y are the names of the people then you don't need "person".

Comment: @KillingTime ok thanks, so removing "person" make sentence to correct one right?

Comment: "The food will be served either by X of W catering service or Y of Z catering service." If it's formal, I'd prefer either "Breakfast", "Lunch" or "Dinner" to "The food". If it's more than one of those, then "Meals" is more elegant than "The food".

Comment: That is how _respectively_ is used in English. However, I don't think your sentence is very clear.

Comment: This may be a duplicate question. Compare https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/295447/ and https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/97014/.

Comment: Better: "*The food will be served by X or Y, from W and Z catering services, respectively*"